# Array Count by Week in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to create a running column array that counts the number of occurrences by person by week. It can't be a pivot table or separate array table but a calculated column that updates beside the raw data. I think I need a combination of an array, vlookup, and query, but I am unsure how to do it.

Here is an example of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KtFZX4K2LmPqgm1PDQ28i2GcbrVEr4TYwzKjbQiZs_U/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814725/group-by-id-and-count-by-sub-unique-id-in-google-sheet-or-excel
Creating a `WeekNumber` column and grouping the data that way. (The attempt is in the spreadsheet example).

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: This question was bumped by Community user. While links to external resources might be helpful, all the relevant details should be included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use:

`=countifs($B$2:$B$10,B2,$A$2:$A$10,A2)`

but the results are different than the column 'desired_count', whose logic i couldn't really understand.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it by creating 2 helper columns: `WeekNumber` and a unique id column. From there I used array, query, and vlookup. It's not the most elegant solution but it works!

The solved function is in the original google sheet link under the `FINAL` column.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment added to the question, posts should be self-contained. In this case, all the relevant details that corresponds to the answer should be included in the answer.